# automatic IIS worker process recycle fails

Tags: iis-6, worker-process, iis

The server is set to its default configuration to recycle the app pool every 1740 minutes. When this happens the following message is logged:

```
A worker process with process id of '1234' serving application pool 'XX' has 
requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed 
processing time limit.
```

Directly after logging this message, the web site is unresponsive. The only way to get it back online is by running `iisreset` manually.

Does anyone know a fix for this behavior, other than turning the recycle feature off? Is it a known problem?

**EDIT1:**

The problem has been isolated to a specific patch release. I'll be researching the changes in the patch in the coming week, and update / answer this question with the solution or more detailed problem depending on what I'll find

Comment: Is the app pool up or down before you issue the iireset, have you checked?  What version of IIS?  What is your app? C#?  Lastly what do you mean by unresponsive - what's the specific error you see?

Comment: The way to reproduce this without waiting 1740 minutes is by hitting the website, recycling the app pool, and keep refreshing it a few times during the recycle. I'm not sure about the error message, Chrome says it's empty content, firefox says it's 200 OK, and a monitoring tool in fact says its 500. According to IIS log the responses are 200 OK, with a content length of 0

Comment: What is your web app written in?

Comment: It's written in C# / ASP.NET

Comment: Did you ever get closer to the solution for this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

**EDITS in bold:**

You either have SharePoint or Exchange **or Some Application** installed/configured on the IIS Server. When recycling of the worker process happens i.e. after every 1720 minutes **internally the command used is "`IISRESET`"**. But, **since the recycling has taken more time than normal** for graceful shutdown which exceedes the default time-out value i.e. 60 seconds and hence the event. **During this recycling of the worker process you won't find any downtime as when the old process is going down a new process is created and its takes care of the new requests**. Check this article [How Worker Process Recycling Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/hi-in/library/cc786980(en-us,WS.10).aspx)

The Event seen would be something like

> Event Type: Information
>  Event
>   Source: W3SVC 
> Event Category: None
>   
> Event ID: 1074 
> Description: A
>   worker process with process id of
>   '1234' serving application pool
>   'sameappPool' has requested a recycle
>   because the worker process reached its
>   allowed processing time limit.

To overcome the issue, the recycle command should be "`IISRESET /NOFORCE`" such that it allows for the services to stop them gracefully.

Comment: It is *not* `iisreset` that is executed every 1740 minutes. It's called a recycle, not a reset. A recycle happens without downtime.
Also, I don't have SharePoint or Exchange running, nor can I set the recycle event to be something else. It's also not related to the timeout value which is 90 seconds by default. A timeout during startup or shutdown causes a slightly different message to be logged.